# fs.read API in Node.js - what does the position argument do?

Tags: node.js

[Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) says `fs.read` takes several arguments, one of them being `position`, which "Specifies where to begin reading from in the file."

However, the docs then say: "If position is an integer, the file position will be unchanged." (docs say the same thing for `fs.readSync`, and refer the reader back to `fs.read`)

I thought we would declare a file `position` like the `offset` argument for where to write to in the output buffer, which takes an integer value of bytes (`0` to start at beginning of the output buffer).

Does anyone know how this is supposed to work? I've tried playing around in the REPL but haven't been able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Because `fs.read` can be called multiple times.
So Node will calculate the `position` for you internally.
For example, when you are reading a text file with content `abcdef`, the code could be like below.

```
const fs = require('fs')

const buffer = Buffer.alloc(1)
const fd = fs.openSync('./1.txt', 'r+')
// at begining, position is 0
let read = fs.readSync(fd, buffer)
// print a
console.log(Buffer.from(buffer,0, read).toString())
// now position is 1
read = fs.readSync(fd, buffer)
// print b, position is 2
console.log(Buffer.from(buffer,0, read).toString())
// if you specify postion : 0, positon is unchanged, it's still 2
read = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, {
    position: 0
})
// print a
console.log(Buffer.from(buffer,0, read).toString())
// continue
read = fs.readSync(fd, buffer)
// print c, position is 3
console.log(Buffer.from(buffer,0, read).toString())
```

Comment: thanks, does this mean we're not supposed to set the `position` parameter at all? if so, why offer it as an argument?